# HTML Tags in Google Calendar Event Descriptions

Tags: html, calendar, google-calendar-api

I work for shared calendar service. Idea is to have all personal calendars from different vendors in same page.
I`ve got situation if I receive event invitation from Office365 in my Google calendar - all html tags (from description field) are added to my Google calendar like plain text. If I clean ones in Google calendar I have a risk if event will be changed in Google calendar - modified description (cleaned from tags) will be shared to another calendar vendors.

As result user expects similar description in different calendars but not html tags. To make it easy I can leave it as it is. To make it good working I've considered different algorithms. All of them need additional rules, some duplicated fields and extra validations.

Years before [`HTML Tags in Google Calendar Event Description`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-calendar-help-dataapi/ZgKSN9f4WDk/2lsGZIrbJBcJ) was pushed to Google, but it is not resolved as I see...

Is there any good solution with easy effort, workarounds or which implementation way I should follow?

Comment: I think this question belongs more to webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: @aakash-verma Do you think so because of using phrase `HTML Tags`?

Comment: No, because it is not related to programming at all and is more related to the web app Google Calendar.